# How to Design Pentaho Kettle (data integration) Job/Transformation Which is Run On Server?

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, data-integration

I am new to pentaho kettle (data integration). The version we use here is the community edition version 5.0.
The case is I would like to design a job & transformations which requires files (big ones) which are located within a remote server. This server can be accessed through ftps. And it is preferred that the job/transformation is run on the server due to our workstation resource limitations.

Could anybody tell me how to design jobs/transformations to be run on the server? If, however, the process cannot be done the way I queried above, is there any available way to do so with other ETL tools?
Any advice will be good for me :) Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can run jobs from the command line by invoking the kitchen.sh script (for jobs) or pan.sh (for transformations).

Answer (score 0):

you can create job and in this under file transfer category diff options of FTP are available, so use use any of those in you job creation and you can easily fetch files from server and use it for your purpose..

Here if you have to use those files for transformation then in 1 job just fetch those files, store it into any specific location and from then design 1 new transformation and in input file step use that file.

[reference](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Get+a+file+with+FTP)